# Is "doc" a reserved Keywords for SQL 2008 or C# or Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, reserved-words

I am designing a large database where the users will produce and store documents. Its a CMS kinda thing.

The table I've created is called "Doc" and then I have a "DocAssets" relation that keeps track of all the things inside the Doc.

The Doc table has a DocID ofcause.

But when I goto Entity Framework model designer and retrieve tables from database, I dont see "Doc" as a table to add.

If I rename Doc to, lets say MDoc for testing purpose. The table shows up nicely when updating from database. If I rename it back to Doc, it disappears from table list.

Now, if its a reserved word, I will figure out something else for naming strategy, but - is it me, is it a bug or is it a reserved word??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) it's not a reserved word.

The "smarter question" would have been: `what would cause a table not to show up?`. Now you are already assuming it is caused by it's name and hinting to reserved words. That might set people trying to help you, but also yourself, off on the wrong track to begin with.

And, might I add, not to rub it in, ofcourse you could have answered the 'reserved word question' yourself easily. Posting the question on SO is actually more work than punching in "[sql server reserved words](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql%20server%20reserved%20words)" in google and clicking "I'm feeling lucky" or the first hit.

Comment: do you have any ideas of what else might cause this behaviour then?

Comment: Not reserved in C# either: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @BerggreenDK Well, EF is as of today, [open source](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkMagicUnicornAndMuchMoreIsNowOpenSourceWithTakeBacks.aspx). So dive in and find out. And let us know ;-)

Comment: @BerggreenDK: Is there something different about that table that would confuse EF?  I know when generating Linq to SQL classes it gets confused sometimes if there's no PK, for example.  Does anything set that table apart?

Comment: @David Then why would renaming it to MDoc (as BerggreenDKK states in his question) solve the problem?

Comment: @David - aaah, I did have another name for that table with a relation. Going to check up. Stay tuned.

Comment: @RobIII: No idea, but it's worth a look I suppose.

Comment: @David True. I'm guessing BerggreenDK is on track of something right now. Maybe some other reference to something (what might have been deleted ages ago) was also named "doc" causing it not to show op.

Comment: okay, I added a database diagram and all tables in the SQL just to see how it looked there. Everything was linked as expected, eventhough the relation was named by the previous old name before I decided to call it Doc.

After that I tried to remove all tables from EDMX and add again. Doc still missing.

Comment: So, I deleted the whole EDMX file. Added a brand new, going through the wizard and questions once again. AND... added tables. TRADAAA! Doc was in the list now as it ought to be.

SO my conclusion is: EDMX files DO get corrupted. :-)

Comment: @BerggreenDK What happens if you create a new project and a fresh database with only one table ("doc") and try the EF on that then? **EDIT** You answered it just before I posted this :-)

Comment: Problem solved, eventhough the answer wasnt really the reason. But I am going to mark it "correct" as it answered my question whether "Doc" was reserved and that was correct too. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Roblll I actually DID Google a lot before writing here and found the SQL list too, but wasnt sure if it was something else I had misunderstood. I also looked at c#, but as I havent done much with the combination (EF4.1+SQL2008+C#+MVC) ... I was rather stuck.